# Basic SQL Query without using subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

tblSales:

```
EmployeeID, 
DailyDate, 
Sales#
```

How can I make a query which returns how many days each employee had the lowest amount of sales#?

I specifically want to run it off a single SQL statement, I have researched this but I just can figure it out! Thanks

Comment: Please can downvoters include reasons for their votes? (I cancelled my own downvote after the question was updated to include table structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am slightly confused as the title and the content of this question don't seem to correlate. The title refers to a subform which doesn't seem relevant. The question also states you are able to do it using a subquery, but you want to do it in one statement, but a query with a subquery is still one statement.

As such I am taking from the question your main question: **"How can I make a query which returns how many days each employee had the least sales#?"**, and the fact that you want to achieve this in **one** statement. In which case you can use:

```
SELECT  T.EmployeeID,
        COUNT(*) AS MinDays
FROM    YourTable T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  DailyDate, MIN([Sales#]) AS MinSales
            FROM    YourTable
            GROUP BY DailyDate
        ) T2
            ON T2.DailyDate = T.DailyDate
            AND T2.[MinSales] = T.[Sales#]
GROUP BY T.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Does the query I have posted not serve this purpose?

Comment: Sorry i'm very new to SQL so there's a good chance i'm doing something wrong here, I'm getting an error saying 'Circular reference caused by alias 'Sales' in query defintion's SELECT list'

Comment: I have made a slight edit. Please try again

Comment: Its asking me to input a parameter value for Sales now

Comment: Another change, I had assumed that the `#` in `Sales#` was not part of the column name.

Comment: Great that sorted it! I should have picked up on that at-least lol, Thanks